# NaN while opening csv file in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am trying to open a csv file in Google colab. I read file with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("airsim_rec.csv", 'r')
```

When i try to see this dataset `df.head()`. I get a `NaN` value [image]

I tried to import this file with different ways.

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()
```

Another

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Both of them didn't work. CSV file is not damaged. When i tried to open it with the same commands on my drive it opened perfectly. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: why are you passing `r` as an argument ? Try without passing it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I just didn't pass `r` as an argument.